# How fixed compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect Tenjin but I am faced with an error like this:

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\project\app\src\main\java\project\shops\com\Splash.java:32: error: cannot access TenjinSDK
> import com.tenjin.android.TenjinSDK;
> ^
> bad class file: C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3af8be2a317a2cde9574b953bbdc025f\jetified-tenjin-api.jar(com/tenjin/android/TenjinSDK.class)
> class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
> Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Can you tell me what could be the reason and how it can be solved, the project does not want to build?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I‘m not familiar with android or tenjin but this error looks like you’re using an older JDK to build your project (looks like Java 8 - corresponds to class version 52) but the TenjinSDK library was built using a newer JDK (seemingly Java 11 - corresponds to class version 55). From the tenjin page it looks like they [moved from Java 8 to 11 with version 1.12.7 of the library](https://github.com/tenjin/tenjin-android-sdk/releases/tag/v1.12.7).

To resolve this problem either use a more recent JDK for the project (recommended) or use a version of tenjin that is compatible with Java 8 (anything below 1.12.7 should do). Using a newer JDK is recommended to be able to update the library in the future. Otherwise you’d be tied to using this specific version.

Comment: Changed jdk to 11, everything connected, thanks)